# group $G$ such that $|G| = p^k$ for some prime $p$ and some integer $k > 1$, where $|g| = p$ for every $g \in G \setminus {\epsilon}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

***Question:***
Give an example of a group $G$ such that $|G| = p^k$ for some prime $p$ and some integer $k > 1$, where $|g| = p$ for every $g \in G \setminus {\epsilon}$.
***My Reasoning :***
I wasn't too sure how to approach this question. Would the group $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ be such a group? I wasn't too sure because the operation of this group is addition and not multiplication so I can't take powers of elements, which is what this question asks. for example : $(1,0)^2 = (1,0)$  $\neq$ $(0,0)$.
I also thought that I can just take the general Klein group where: $V = \{1, a,b,c\mid a^2=b^2=c^2\}$. Are these two groups good examples? if not, what other group can I pick?

Comment: If you use multiplicative notation, $a^n$ is a shorthand for an n-fold product $a \cdots a$. If you use additive notation, you write $n\cdot a$, which then means $a + \cdots + a$ ($n$ times). If the problem statement uses multiplicative notation, it does not restrict you to it - use can use additive notation too, just translate carefully products to sums and powers to products.

Comment: If you follow ALG's remark, both your examples are valid for your problem. [Note also that the two examples you give are isomorphic groups, just keep in mind the operations are multiplication in one of them and addition in the other.

Comment: $g^n$ just means "the group operation being applied to $g$ $n$ times"; or, more visually, $\underbrace{g\cdot g\cdot ...\cdot g}_{n\text{ times}}$. It doesn't matter if the group operation is addition or multiplication or something else entirely.

Comment: Those two groups are actually... one, i.e. they are isomorphic. More generally, $C_p\times C_p$ has that property, for every prime $p$.

Comment: To make this more interesting, try to find a *non-abelian* group with this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally:
$$G=C_p\times C_p$$
where $C_p$ is the cyclic group of order $p$ (in multiplicative notation), has those properties: it has order $p^2$ and every nontrivial element has order $p$. Your example (one, actually, as $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2\cong V$) is just the special case for $p=2$. So, yes, it is a good example.